# Snapshot from StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a ListView inside a Streambuilder with data from Cloud Firestore.
Here you have the code:

```
//inicio stream
                                              StreamBuilder<List<Evento>>(
                                                  stream: eventosProvider
                                                      .eventosbares,
                                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                                    if (snapshot
                                                        .data.isNotEmpty) {
                                                      return SizedBox(
                                                        height: 155,
                                                        child: ListView.builder(
                                                            scrollDirection:
                                                                Axis.horizontal,
                                                            itemCount: snapshot
                                                                .data.length,
                                                            itemBuilder:
                                                                (context,
                                                                    index) {
                                                              var dateString =
                                                                  snapshot
                                                                      .data[
                                                                          index]
                                                                      .fechaEvento;
                                                              var date = DateFormat(
                                                                      'd-M-yyyy HH:mm',
                                                                      'de_DE')
                                                                  .parse(
                                                                      dateString);

                                                              return Card(
                                                                shape:
                                                                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                  borderRadius:
                                                                      BorderRadius
                                                                          .circular(
                                                                              10),
                                                                ),
                                                                child:
                                                                    Container(
                                                                  height: 178,
                                                                  width: 280,
                                                                  child: Column(
                                                                      children: [
                                                                        Padding(
                                                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                              left: 8.0,
                                                                              right: 8.0,
                                                                              top: 8.0),
                                                                          child:
                                                                              ClipRRect(
                                                                            borderRadius:
                                                                                BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                                                            child:
                                                                                Image.network(
                                                                              snapshot.data[index].imagenEvento,
                                                                              width: 278.0,
                                                                              height: 80.0,
                                                                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                                            ),
                                                                          ),
                                                                        ),
                                                                        Padding(
                                                                          padding:
                                                                              const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                                          child:
                                                                              Row(
                                                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                                MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                                            children: [
                                                                              CircleAvatar(
                                                                                radius: 20.0,
                                                                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].fotoPerfilAutor),
                                                                                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                                                              ),
                                                                              Padding(
                                                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                                                                child: Container(
                                                                                  width: 150,
                                                                                  child: Column(
                                                                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                                                    children: [
                                                                                      Text(
                                                                                        snapshot.data[index].tituloEvento,
                                                                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                                          fontSize: 13,
                                                                                        ),
                                                                                      ),
                                                                                      Text(
                                                                                        DateFormat('EEEEE dd MMM yyyy   HH:mm', 'es_ES').format(date),
                                                                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                                                                      ),
                                                                                    ],
                                                                                  ),
                                                                                ),
                                                                              ),
                                                                              SizedBox(
                                                                                width: 10,
                                                                              ),
                                                                              Text(
                                                                                snapshot.data[index].num_invitados,
                                                                                style: TextStyle(color: ColoresApp.naranjaTop, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14),
                                                                              ),
                                                                              SizedBox(
                                                                                width: 5,
                                                                              ),
                                                                              CircleAvatar(
                                                                                radius: 10.0,
                                                                                backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/friends.png"),
                                                                                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                                                              )
                                                                            ],
                                                                          ),
                                                                        ),
                                                                      ]),
                                                                ),
                                                              );
                                                            }),
                                                      );
                                                    } else {
                                                      return Text(
                                                        "No hay eventos en bares",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color:
                                                                Colors.white),
                                                      );
                                                    }
                                                  }),
```

I am getting the following exception using this code, the app is not exiting, it only shows a red error background for a moment, but it is not acceptable:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<List<Evento>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<List<Evento>, AsyncSnapshot<List<Evento>>>#d6fd3):
The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isNotEmpty
```

I have tried changing the line:

```
if (snapshot.data.isNotEmpty)
```

with

```
if (snaphot.hasData)
```

but then, the exception is gone, but there is a blank space thrown, not the else part of the if clause.

What should I do to know if the snapshop has really data or is waiting to get them?

EDIT

Here you have the service loading the Stream:

```
Stream<List<Evento>> getEventosBares(){


    return _db
        .collection('eventos').where('interes', isEqualTo: 'bares')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Evento.fromJson(doc.data()))
        .toList());
  }
```

And here you have the provider:

```
Stream<List<Evento>> get eventosbares => firestoreService.getEventosBares();
```

Comment: I think something is wrong with your stream here eventosProvider.eventosbares. try removing the else keyword and just return the text widget after if block and see the results. the error says there is no eventosbares for the provider u called it on. check that.

Comment: @Benyamin, I have included in my question the source of the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a null check:

```dart
builder: (context, snapshot) {
 if (snapshot.data != null && snapshot.data.isNotEmpty) {
   return SizedBox(...);
```